On properties of sums involving the floor function
During my research on properties of fractional part and integer part functions, I was led to consider the function of two variables $f(n,k)=\frac{2^{k}+1}{2^{ n}+1}\left\lfloor \frac{2^{n}+1}{2^{k}+1}\right\rfloor$. What interests me with these functions is to estimate the sums
$$S_{m}(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{m}f(n,k)$$
It seems that for every integer $m\geq0 $ there exists a polynomial $P_{m}$ of degree $m$ with integer coefficients such that we have this limit property invariant according to the parity of $n$:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(S_{m}(2n)-\sum_{k=1}^{2n}k^{m}+P_{m}(2n)\right)\frac{ 2^{n}}{n^{m}}=3$$
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(S_{m}(2n+1)-\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}k^{m}+P_{m}(2n+1) \right)\frac{2^{n}}{n^{m}}=2$$
Here are the first polynomials $P_m$ which experimentally verify this property
$P_{0}(n)=1$
$P_{1}(n)=n-2$
$P_{2}(n)=n^{2}-4n+6$
$P_{3}(n)=n^{3}-6n^{2}+18n-26$
$P_{4}(n)=n^{4}-8n^{3}+36n^{2}-104n+150$
$P_{5}(n)=n^{5}-10n^4+60n^3-260n^2+750n-1082$
$P_{6}(n)=n^{6}-12n^5+90n^4-520n^3+2250n^2-6492n+9366$
I don't see how to demonstrate it and already get a formula for $P_m$. Thank you for your ideas.
ps: From the answer below $P_m$ are given by
$$P_{m}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{m}(-1)^{k}{m \choose k}A000629(k)x^{m-k}$$
where A000629 is the sequence at https://oeis.org/A000629

Perhaps a more easy-to-prove formula for $|P_m(0)|$ is $\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{k^m}{2^k}$ for $m>0$.

Sorry I am confused, could you explain? I get$$\left(S_m(2\times1)-\sum_{k=1}^{2\times1}k^m+\frac{19}{10}\right)\frac{2^1}{1^m}=3$$and$$\left(S_m(2\times2)-\sum_{k=1}^{2\times2}k^m+\frac{32\times 3^m+59\times 2^m+8}{68}\right)\frac{2^2}{2^m}=3,$$is this correct? If yes, how does this agree with your $P_m$? If no, why?

@TheBestMagician Yes, this seems consistent with the presence of powers of 2.

@მამუკა ჯიბლაძე    You didn't read correctly.

Let us check the sequences then. With me, $S_m(2)$ is $\frac85$, $\frac{13}5$, $\frac{23}5$, $\frac{43}5$, $\frac{83}5$, $\frac{163}5$, $\frac{323}5$, ... and $S_m(4)$ is $\frac{56}{17}$, $\frac{140}{17}$, $\frac{428}{17}$, $\frac{1466}{17}$, $\frac{5336}{17}$, $\frac{20090}{17}$, ... (for $m=0,1,2,...$), is this correct?

No $m$ is fixed.

What do you mean? You have numbers $S_m(n)$ for all $m,n\geqslant0$, right? So in particular you do have sequences $S_m(2)$, $m=0,1,...$ and $S_m(4)$, $m=0,1,...$, no?

But OK let us check sequences with fixed $m$ then. I get $S_0(n)=0,1,\frac{8}{5},\frac{23}{9},\frac{56}{17},\frac{140}{33},\frac{68}{13},\frac{264}{43},...$ and $S_1(n)=0,1,\frac{13}{5},\frac{46}{9},\frac{140}{17},\frac{37}{3},\frac{1141}{65},\frac{1007}{43},...$, is this correct?

Yes it is correct but I'm not going to validate all your calculations?

You said "You didn't read correctly", so I am trying to figure out where did I make a mistake

The problem is a limit problem when n tends to infinity and m is fixed. That's why I said that.

We first note that $f(n,k)=1-\frac{(2^n+1)\%(2^k+1)}{2^n+1}$. Therefore
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(1-f(n,k)\right)k^m = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{(2^n+1)\%(2^k+1)}{2^n+1}k^m,$$
we can replace the denominators by $2^n$ at the cost of $O(n^{m+1}\cdot 2^{-n})$ and also discard the terms for $k<n/3$ at the cost of $O(n^{m+1}\cdot 2^{-2n/3})$.
Observe that when $n/2\leq k<n$, we have $(2^n+1)\%(2^k+1) = 2^k+2-2^{n-k}$, and when $n/3\leq k<n/2$ we have $(2^n+1)\%(2^k+1)=2^{n-2k}+1.$
Then the sum is
$$\sum_{n/2\leq k<n}\frac{2^k+2-2^{n-k}}{2^n}k^m+\sum_{n/3\leq k<n/2}\left(2^{-2k}+2^{-n}\right)\cdot k^m+O(n^{m+1}\cdot 2^{-2n/3})$$
$$=\sum_{1\leq k\leq n/2}\left(2^{-k}-2^{k-n}\right)(n-k)^m+O(n^{m+1}\cdot 2^{-2n/3}).$$
Set $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2^{-k}(n-k)^m$ to be the polynomial $P_m(n)$.
Then this is
$$P_m(n)-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2^{-\max(n-k,k)}(n-k)^m+O(n^{m+1}\cdot 2^{-2n/3})$$
$$=P_m(n)-n^m\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2^{-\max(k,n-k)}\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^m+O(n^{m+1}\cdot 2^{-2n/3}).$$
Note that the main contribution comes from $|k-n/2|<1000\log n$, and so we can safely replace $1-k/n$ by $1/2$.
If $n$ is even, then the middle term is $n^m\cdot 2^{-n/2}\cdot 2^{-m}\cdot (3+o(1))$ as $(2^{-0}+2^{-1}+\cdots)+(2^{-1}+2^{-2}+\cdots) = 3$.
If $n$ is odd, we can similarly compute this as $n^m\cdot 2^{-n/2}\cdot 2^{-m}\cdot (2\sqrt{2}+o(1))$ as $2(2^{-0.5}+2^{-1.5}+\cdots) = 2\sqrt{2}$.

I misread the expression and thought 2^n was supposed to be 2^2n. I think the computation is still roughly the same though.

Thank you for this update. All is clear.
